# Why does my GCC compiler not compile C code?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, c, gcc

I followed a YouTube tutorial for installing the gcc compiler on my Windows 10 machine. The install appeared to go perfectly. [tutorial here](https://youtu.be/sXW2VLrQ3Bs).

I then wrote a C program, which compiles and executes when I check it using online compilers. However, when I run my command prompt and navigate to the directory with my file `gcc_test.c` and type `gcc gcc_test.c` nothin changes in the directory. I don't see a `.tds` or `.exe` file like I did with my previous compiler so there is no `gcc_test.exe` file for me to run.

I was sure to add the bin folder to my PATH so I don't understand why the command `gcc` does nothing. Does anyone know why it does not compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally, gcc always names the executable "a.out" unless told otherwise.

You should use:

```
gcc -o gcc_test.exe gcc_test.c
```

You can probably also use:

```
make gcc_test
```

Comment: Okay, so I did notice a file `a.exe`. That was it! Thank you! So the `-o` is telling gcc what to output as the file name? Thank you.